# Start systemd service after DRM card0 device

Tags: systemd

I have kiosk display running an electron app.
This app needs to be started on boot.

```
[Unit]
Description=Display Application
After=network.target getty@tty1.service
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/electron main.js -- :0 -nocursor -nolisten tcp
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But for some reason this service ist started to early and xinit complains with no screens found. After the first systemd restart the app is running.

I searchd [systemd device](https://superuser.com/questions/1469766/make-systemd-service-wait-for-a-device-generically) which sounded promising. But using `dev-dri-card0` as `Requires` and `After` results in `Missing Dependency` in startup.

```
# ls /dev/dri
by-path  card0  renderD128

# dmesg | grep drm
[    3.609070] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    3.672741] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    3.673192] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    4.327074] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    4.332654] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin (v1.7)
[    4.356201] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Panel advertises DPCD backlight support, but VBT disagrees. If your backlight controls don't work try booting with i915.enable_dpcd_backlight=1. If your machine needs this, please file a _new_ bug report on drm/i915, see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/wikis/How-to-file-i915-bugs for details.
[    4.367399] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20200917 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    4.376167] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    4.402186] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
```

```
# systemctl list-units -a -t device | grep card0
  dev-dri-card0.device          loaded inactive dead    /dev/dri/card0
```

I have no glue whats wrong here. Found some posts saying that `drm` module is loaded to late (after systemd) ... added `drm` to initramfs ... no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution

```
[Unit]
Description=Display Application
After=network.target systemd-user-sessions.service
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
TTYPath=/dev/tty1
PAMName=systemd-user
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/electron main.js -- :0 -quiet -nocursor -nolisten tcp
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
Alias=display-manager.service
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This way the `systemd-logind` brings up a user session and all the `drm` stuff is ready.